# How can I setText when ImageButton is click in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog, settext

> I am building an android application where the user select the
>   favorite android app.
>
> The user select there favorite app by clicking on ImageButton.
>
> Now when The user click the ImageButton an dialogbox is open.
>
> Here is dialog box code -

```
        public void start() {

        final CharSequence[] items = {
                "Poor","Avg.","Good","Very-good","Execlent"
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Rank Your self");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // Do something with the selection
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       

                // txt1.setText(item);
                //String item2 = txt1.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

> Now Basically I wanna when user Click on the ImageButton this dialog
>   box is open.
>
> When user select any of rank as mention in dialogbox the text below
>   that particular image displayed the rank that was select in dialogbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)`

accepts an integer value `item`.

Now you have an array of items defined by

`final CharSequence[] items = {
  "Poor","Avg.","Good","Very-good","Execlent"
   };`

To access an element of the array use `items[item]` where `item` is the index of your array.

This will return that particular string of the array.

Return that back to a string say `itemst`

Finally set the text to `txt1` with `txt1.setText(itemst);`
within the `onClick` function

You could also obtain the value by

`public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
   int which, boolean isChecked) {
   if (isChecked){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),items[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}`

to generate a toast of the selected item.

Comment: Thanks! can please give an example as I am new to android... please help

Comment: What kind of an example?
Simply use items[item] to get the selected item you need.
The second solution is another way as well.
Eg itemst=items[item]
Where items is a string and item is the index of your aray

Comment: Its showing error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String. I am using like this -  public void start() {final CharSequence[] items = {"Beginner","Amateur","Semi Pro","Pro","Legend"};AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Rank Your self");
         builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {// Do something with the   selectionitemst=items[item];}});AlertDialog alert =builder.create();alert.show();}

Comment: Can you please tell me how to empty the string value that I set to textView.

Comment: Just use .setText("")

Answer (score 1):

`item` is the number of item. `items` is an array containing all texts. You get the selected text like this:

```
String text = items[item];
```